# Preview File in Browser is not working in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, browser, glassfish

Working in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 and using glassfish server for JavaEE Web Application, the preview file in browser option is not working.

[image: Image Attached]

Not even a single browser is opening to display the results. I have to restart the glassfish server again and again to view the changes.

Comment: Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had some servlet mapping code inside the web.xml file. After removing the code for servlet mapping and defining the `urlpattern` inside the servlet java class, the IDE is working properly.